# How do I configure my web application for Binding with core service?

Tags: 2013, core-service, content-manager

I am developing a ASP.NET (C#) web application that will run on a Content Manager server which will use Tridion 2013 core service.

How should I configure my web application to use core service?
Should I just reference the core service assemblies in my project or I also have to configure an end point?

I have seen many examples but mostly using MVC, which I am not doing.

I am building a simple web application which will use core service to add/modify/delete Tridion users, get publication details report, etc.

Any sample project would be really appreciated

Answer (score 8):

If you're starting out with the Core Service then I'd highly recommend that you check out the [Core Service Recipes](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/CookbookDocumentation#core-service-recipies) section of [the Tridion Practice project](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice) on GitHub.

This has examples of getting a Core Service client [with](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithConfigFile) and [without](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithoutConfigFile) a config file.

I would also recommend reading the [Interacting with the Core Service from client-side .NET](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9575DB42-91DB-4AED-B2C0-BE97F27DB23C) section of the online documentation thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

Below are the steps you may follow to get started .

> **STEP 1**: Identifying the Core Service Endpoints:

The Tridion Core Service End Points are present in the file: `Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll.config` at Path:  `%TRIDION_HOME%\bin\client\` on the Tridion Server.

They will look something as below:

```
<client>

      <endpoint name="basicHttp_2013" 
               address="http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/basicHttp" 
               binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
               contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService"/>
      <!-- Some More Endpoints will be there here -->
</client>
```

> **STEP 2**: Adding reference to Core Service

- Add reference to the Tridion DLL:   `Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll`
- Add the Service Endpoints in your `Web.Config` (Web Applications ) or in  your `App.config` if using any Console Project.

> **STEP 3**: Initializing the Core Service

Create a Class and initialize the Core Service in the Constructor of the class. Supply the required UserName / Password and use any of the End Points as in Step 1

```
public class TridionCoreServiceHelper
    {
        // This EndPoint Name is in the Config as mentioned above
        private readonly string endpointName = "basicHttp_2013";
        public TridionCoreServiceHelper()
        {
          client = new CoreServiceClient(endpointName);
          client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = // User_Name
          client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = //Password
        }    

       private CoreServiceClient client;
    }
```

> **STEP 4:** Querying using Tridion Core Service

Once the Service is initialized, Perform the Queries like the *Publications List*, *Publication Targets* ...

```
    public XElement GetPublicationList()
        {
            PublicationsFilterData filter = new PublicationsFilterData();
            return client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
        }

    public XElement GetPublicationTargetList()
        {
            PublicationTargetsFilterData filter = new PublicationTargetsFilterData();
            return client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
        }
```

Get the Users:

```
public XElement GetUserGrouptList()
        {
            UsersFilterData filter = new UsersFilterData();
            return client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
        }
```

**SAMPLE PROJECT:** Check this one of the best sample Project by Yabolka on Git Hub

URL : https://github.com/yabolka/TridionCoreServiceAPI

Comment: Note that if you host your web application in the CM website, you don't have to worry about the Core Service endpoint configuration: your web app will inherit the configuration defined in the CM website root's web.config.

Comment: Great Point Rick !

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code below to create a core service client in your web application:

```
/// <summary>
/// Core service client configuration
/// </summary>
/// <returns>return the client detail</returns>
public static CoreServiceClient GetCoreServiceSettings()
{
   var binding = new NetTcpBinding
   {
       MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
       ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
       {
           MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
           MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
       }
    };

    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2013/netTcp");

    var client = new CoreServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
    client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(
                                                                     "YourAdminUserID",
                                                                     "Password");
    return client;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define `<bindings><basicHttpBinding> inside <System.serviceModel>`  of your config file.
Then add your:- `<client><endpoint name="basicHttp_2013" **or** <endpoint name="netTcp_2013"`

```
  <client>
      <endpoint name="basicHttp_2013" address="http://1.1.1.1/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService" />
      <endpoint name="streamDownload_basicHttp_2013" address="http://1.1.1.1/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/streamDownload_basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamDownload_basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.IStreamDownload" />
      <endpoint name="streamUpload_basicHttp_2013" address="http://1.1.1.1/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamUpload_basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.IStreamUpload" />

      <endpoint name="netTcp_2013" address="net.tcp://localhost:protnumber/CoreService/2013/netTcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService" />
    </client>
```

then 
-----------------------Create client---------------------------

```
CoreServiceClient client = new CoreServiceClient("basicHttp_2013"); // If outside the server 
    or
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("netTcp_2013");  // From localhost    
client.Impersonate("userName");
```

Sample project is stated in above answers